# Intuitive explanation of complex-valued function and a notation

Tags: complex-analysis

Recently I have introduced to a new concept and a new notation while learning complex analysis.
The new concept is complex-valued function and the new notation is $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$.
I'm familiar with the notation of function. Nevertheless, I have never seen the above notation before.Can anyone give an intuitive explanation of complex-valued function and the notation?

Comment: It simply means that f takes a complex number as input and gives a complex number as output. e.g. $f(z) = z^2$ for any complex number z. Complex analysis then goes on to making sense of functions like $e^z, sin(z), ln(z)$ and so on which may be defined on all of $\mathbb{C}$ or just subsets.

Answer (score 0):

$f: A \to B$ just means that $f$ is a function defined on the set $A$ with values in the set $B$.  $\mathbb C$ is the set of complex numbers.